# How to change arguments when tornado render html ？

Tags: url, arguments, render, tornado, requesthandler

Example code:

```
RequestHandlerA(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get/post(self):
       ...
       redirect('/index?username=user0&password=user0')
       ...

RequestHandlerB(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get/post(self):
       ...
       render('index.html')
       ...
```

`RequestHandlerA` redirects to `RequestHandlerB` which then renders the `index.html`.

At this point, the browser's URL looks like this :

```
/index?username=user0&password=user0
```

I'd like to remove the `username` and `password` arguments from the URL. How can I do that?

The "redirect" is **necessary**. So, what can I do in `RequestHandlerB` for this question?

Comment: Why not make a redirect like `redirect('/index')`? Also, it is a bad practice to log a user in using a GET request, because this way the password is the part of the URL and it will be saved in the browser history.

Comment: **`redirect('/index')`**  will not contain the usename and password , how can i send these informations to RequestHandlerB?

Comment: Oh, I can set the cookies.